# How do I correctly resolve es6 modules in a project using jspm's paths config in my mocha test file

Tags: mocha.js, jspm, es6-module-loader

We've got a jspm config.js which contains the following settings:

```
baseUrl: "/A_count",
paths: {
    "js/*": "src/js/*.js"
}
```

This effectively allows us to use cleaner import statements, instead of having to stub out relative paths.  Our directory structure looks like this:

```
A_count
-src
--js
---collections
----accounts.js
---models
----account.js
---views
-test
--models
---models.js
```

So in accounts.js, instead of having to write `import Account from '../models/account'`, we write `import Account from 'js/models/account'`

My issue now is in test/models/models.js, I `import` the different models, using their correct relative paths (ie `../../src/js/models/account`) in order to test them, and those models also contain their own dependencies which they are importing using the path which makes sense given the jspm config.  What happens is that "Mocha exploded!" along with saying that the models are importing dependencies which can't be found, because they rely on the mapping found in the jspm config.

How can I maintain the jspm mapping for the tests, so as to avoid having to set the relative paths of each component being tested, just for the tests sake?

We use grunt for our build tool and I am currently running the (soon-to-be) tests with grunt-mocha-test.

Comment: Do you run mocha in the browser? Do you load System.js with the same config before mocha? I have created a project to simplify test setup for JSPM-powered projects https://github.com/OrKoN/jspm-testem and with it I had no problems with path resolution. I would love to hear your feedback.

Comment: We're not running mocha in the browser thus far, just as part of the grunt build process.  The grunt mocha plugin takes care of transpiling the es6 (much like running the command `mocha --compilers js:babel/register`) so I didn't think about loading System.js, but where exactly would I do that with regards to grunt?  Would I load System.js and then pass it the config.js at the top of the test script before the other imports?

Comment: The problem is that `paths` configuration only works with SystemJS. So when you just transpile and run your code in node, the node's module resolver cannot know that everything that starts with `js` should be looked up in the `src/js` folder. So you need either to load and configure System.js first (I don't know if it's possible with Node/grunt) and then import all of your modules using systemjs module loader or to tweak node's loader.  For instance, smth like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-alias may help (I have not used it personally).